# Alternative way of finding the frequency of a term and process the respective values

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv

I have a question regarding the structure of my code. I have the following csv

```
name product country
 A     game1   USA
 A     game2   USA 
 B     bis     World
 .
 .
```

Basically, the name of each vendor appears multiple times (as many as the number of products the vendor has). My purpose is to create a csv which contains the name of the vendor, number of products and the country(if the value is "world" I will assign 5 or else 1). So far I have not managed to do using a more algorithmic mindset. Instead I have used the next code

```
df = pd.read_csv("testtest.csv") 

num_listings = df['vendor_name'].value_counts().to_dict()

print(num_listings)
```

and then I converted the dictionary to a csv file. I assume that using a for loop could make my code easier since I could use a counter and as long as the name remains the same just use that counter. I do not know how should i approach it. I already tried the following but it did not work.

```
ds = pd.read_csv("testtest.csv", index_col = 'vendor_name') 

x=0
for index in ds:
  if ds['index'] == ds['index']:
    x=x+1
print(x)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby.agg` with a dictionary of aggregation functions for each column.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'product': pd.Series.nunique,
     'country': lambda x: 5 if (x=='World').any() else 1}
df.groupby('name').agg(d).reset_index()
```

#### Output:

```
  name  product  country
0    A        2        1
1    B        1        5
```

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for  but it raises an dtype exception. I will specify the dtype and let you know. But I cannot understand why it raises an exception.

Comment: After specifying the dtype it works perfectly. Thank you @ALollz .